# What permissions are required to create Cognito User Pool with SMS MFA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-cognito

I've attached "AmazonCognitoPowerUser" policy with permissions below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "cognito-idp:*",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListOpenIdConnectProviders",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:ListSAMLProviders",
                "iam:GetSAMLProvider",
                "kinesis:ListStreams",
                "lambda:GetPolicy",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "sns:GetSMSSandboxAccountStatus",
                "sns:ListPlatformApplications",
                "ses:ListIdentities",
                "ses:GetIdentityVerificationAttributes",
                "mobiletargeting:GetApps",
                "acm:ListCertificates"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                        "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com",
                        "email.cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:GetServiceLinkedRoleDeletionStatus"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/cognito-idp.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonCognitoIdp*",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/email.cognito-idp.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonCognitoIdpEmail*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

User can create a User Pool with MRA Required if it's TOTP only. They cannot create it with SMS MFA, nor can they add SMS MFA afterwards. The error says doesn't have permission but I thought this policy should already allow users to manage Cognito. What permissions are we missing?

I'm thinking it's because SMS MFA requires a Role but they're already able to "Create Role" during the step of the User Pool creation process. It's when they save the user pool that it fails.

Comment: What is the exact error? I cannot seem to be able to reproduce this.

Comment: Have you applied for a spending increase as mentioned in this page? Process of the spending increase is why I had opted out of this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa-sms-text-message.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must request an increased spend limit from Amazon SNS. The default spend limit per account (if not specified) is 1.00 USD per month. If you want to raise the limit, submit an SNS Limit Increase case in the AWS Support Center.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to be a permissions problem.

I had opted not to use the SMS feature just because of one big first step.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa-sms-text-message.html

> To ensure that SMS messages are sent to verify phone numbers and for
> SMS text message MFA, you must request an increased spend limit from
> Amazon SNS.
>
> The default spend limit per account (if not specified) is 1.00 USD per
> month. If you want to raise the limit, submit an SNS Limit Increase
> case in the AWS Support Center. For New limit value, enter your
> desired monthly spend limit. In the Use Case Description field,
> explain that you're requesting an SMS monthly spend limit increase.

We need to apply for the spending increase for the SNS service which is via an AWS Support Center ticket/case (not available via console).

[image]

Support ticket takes weeks to resolve and can be quite irritating, as there are many to and fro communications.

This may not be a complete solution to your problem but as this important question was not active, some discussion may help to push this a bit. I am also trying to set SMS MFA up, surely will take time. Will update this answer when done.